# Android App wont work when i use SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an app for android which has the googleMap integrated with it. For the last couple of months i have been developing with min SDK 12, and all went fine. I managed to use the map perfectly. Today I was trying to change the min SDK to 8,(for more people to use it). For that  I used SupportMapFragment, but the app crashes and doesnt seem to work.

Below is my code.

```
LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/MyAppColor"
            android:orientation="vertical"
             >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map_list"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                 >
            </fragment>

</LinearLayout


my java file

private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {


            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }



my manifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo"
    android:versionCode="104"
    android:versionName="1.0.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.DashBoard"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dash_board"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.ChildCategory"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_child_category"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.BussinessByCategory"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bussiness_by_category"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.BussinessInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bussiness_info"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.FullScreenViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_full_screen_view"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.SearchableActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_searchable"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAi9nb7-zYWA51-cKoG4eveMQ7nVap2gOU" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.MapViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_view" 
          android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />


        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my logcat

```
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.apk.myikubinfo/com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.BussinessByCategory}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2001)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2028)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1179)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.BussinessByCategory.initilizeMap(BussinessByCategory.java:459)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.BussinessByCategory.setMapFeatures(BussinessByCategory.java:622)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at com.dev.apk.myikubinfo.BussinessByCategory.onCreate(BussinessByCategory.java:276)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1965)
02-25 17:41:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing metadata tag in your manifest file:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: i am sorry but i have that metadata tag in my manifest file .